# How to execute and return proper values for parse()

Tags: java, android, xml, parsing, rss

Im trying to code an android RSS reader that will (for now) parse the xml from [this MangaPanda List](http://www.mangapanda.com/alphabetical). I'm using [this Android XML example](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html) for basic structure (and because it uses XMLPullParser) as well as [this example](http://www.ingeniumblog.net/2012/01/making-a-slick-rss-reader-in-android/) because of its clear explanation of its `EfficientAdapter`, `AsyncTask`, and `ListView` usage.

So far I think I've "merged" the two pretty well but I cant quite figure out how to properly execute the parsing process.

My question is: How would I properly implement the `LoadXmlFromNetwork()` so that it would return the proper format for my adapter?

MainActivity:

```
  //Implementation of AsyncTask used to download XML feed from stackoverflow.com.
private class loadingTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
 @Override
 protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
     try {
         return loadXmlFromNetwork(urls[0]);
     } catch (IOException e) {
         return getResources().getString(R.string.hello_world);
     } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
         return getResources().getString(R.string.menu_settings);
     }
 }

 @Override
 protected void onPostExecute(String result) {  
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     // Displays the HTML string in the UI via a WebView
     listview1.setAdapter(new EfficientAdapter(MainActivity.this, Manga));
     ShowProgress.dismiss();
 }

}

public Manga loadXmlFromNetwork(String urlString) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
    InputStream stream = null;
    // Instantiate the parser
    MainParser MainParser = new MainParser();
    List<Manga> mangas = null;
    String mangaAlpha = null;
    String mangaName = null;
    boolean mangaComplete = false;


    try {
        stream = downloadUrl(urlString);        
        mangas = MainParser.parse(stream);
    // Makes sure that the InputStream is closed after the app is
    // finished using it.
    } finally {
        if (stream != null) {
            stream.close();
        } 
     }

    // StackOverflowXmlParser returns a List (called "entries") of Entry objects.
    // Each Entry object represents a single post in the XML feed.
    // This section processes the entries list to combine each entry with HTML markup.
    // Each entry is displayed in the UI as a link that optionally includes
    // a text summary.

    return mangas;
}
 // Given a string representation of a URL, sets up a connection and gets
 // an input stream.
 private InputStream downloadUrl(String urlString) throws IOException {
     URL url = new URL(urlString);
     HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
     conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
     conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
     conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
     conn.setDoInput(true);
     // Starts the query
     conn.connect();
     InputStream stream = conn.getInputStream();
    return stream;      
 }


}
```

MainParser:

```
public class MainParser {

// We don't use namespaces
private static final String ns = null;

public List<Manga> parse(InputStream in) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
    try {
        XmlPullParser parser = Xml.newPullParser();
        parser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES, false);
        parser.setInput(in, null);
        parser.nextTag();
        return readFeed(parser);
    } finally {
        in.close();
    }
}

private List<Manga> readFeed(XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
    List<Manga> mangas = new ArrayList<Manga>();

    parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "feed");
    while (parser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
        if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
            continue;
        }
        String name = parser.getName();
        // Starts by looking for the entry tag
        if (name.equals("li")) {
            mangas.add(readTag(parser));
        } else {
            skip(parser);
        }
    }  
    return mangas;
}

private Manga readTag(XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
    parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "li");
    String mangaAlpha =null;
    String mangaName = null;
    String mangaLink = null;
    boolean mangaComplete = false;

    while (parser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
        if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
            continue;
        }
        String name = parser.getName();
        if (name.equals("a")) {
            mangaAlpha = parser.getAttributeValue(null, "name");
        } else if (name.equals("a")) {
            mangaName = parser.getText();
        } else if (name.equals("a")) {
            mangaLink = parser.getAttributeValue(null, "href");
        } else if (name.equals("span")) {
            mangaComplete = true;
        } else {
            skip(parser);
        }
    }
    return new Manga(mangaAlpha, mangaName, mangaLink, mangaComplete);
}

private void skip(XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
    if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
        throw new IllegalStateException();
    }
    int depth = 1;
    while (depth != 0) {
        switch (parser.next()) {
        case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
            depth--;
            break;
        case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
            depth++;
            break;
        }
    }
 }

}
```

My EfficientAdapter:

```
public class EfficientAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Activity activity;
private ArrayList<Manga> mangadata;
private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;
//public ImageLoader imageLoader;
ViewHolder holder;

EfficientAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<Manga> d) {

    activity = a;
    mangadata = d;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    //imageLoader = new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mangadata.toArray().length;

}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {

    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {

    return position;
}

public static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView label;
    public TextView addr;
    //public ImageView image;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi = convertView;

    if (convertView == null) {
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.textholder, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.label = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        holder.addr = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        //holder.image = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        vi.setTag(holder);
    } else
        holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();

    holder.label.setText(mangadata.get(position).getMangaAlpha());
    holder.addr.setText(mangadata.get(position).getMangaName());

    //imageLoader.DisplayImage((data.get(position).getThumbnail()), activity,
    //      holder.image, 72, 72);

    return vi;
}

}
```

On a side note: I didn't know how much of my code would be necessary to properly explain my problem so please feel free to edit out unnecessary parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your asynctask like that:

```
private class loadingTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<Manga>> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try {
            return loadXmlFromNetwork(urls[0]);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return null;
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<Manga> result) {  
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // Displays the HTML string in the UI via a WebView
        listview1.setAdapter(new EfficientAdapter(MainActivity.this, result));
        ShowProgress.dismiss();
    }
}

public List<Manga> loadXmlFromNetwork(String urlString) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {

....
```

Comment: This did fix the error but created more. I had to set the return values to either `ArrayList<Manga>` or `List<Manga>` but neither will work when I run the app. I'm assuming it has something to do with my parser so I think I'll try using SAX instead.